# how to format datetime in Claudera Hadoop (m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM)

Tags: sql, hadoop, cloudera-cdh

In Cloudera Hadoop, datetime columns has raw data as `2016-02-02T17:41:13.000+0000`.

I could format as:

```
select to_date(a1.createddate) from table1;
```

I need to format as `m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM`. What's the command to format as `2017/01/21 5:15AM`?

Comment: what are you using? Hive or Impala? and mention the version if applicable.

Comment: `2017/01/21` has the year first. Now, look at the pattern again

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using Hive?

If so, you can use the `unix_timestamp` function like so:

`unix_timestamp(date_string, "MM/dd/yy h:mm a")`

You can use any format listed here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html

Comment: When I run in Claudera Hue: select unix_timestamp(a1.createddate, 'MM/dd/yy h:mm a')  from cc_vw_case a1, I got "Bad date/time conversion format: MM/dd/yy h:mm a" error